# Nikon D3400 with YN622N II wireless flash transceiver and YN568EX speedlight. Why won’t my camera take a picture?

Tags: nikon, troubleshooting, yongnuo, wireless-flash

I am using two of the transceivers and two of the speedlights. Everything will sync together, my camera will communicate with the speedlights. Like if I change from f1.8 to f4 it will also change on the speedlights. When the speedlights go into sleep mode I can wake them up by pressing any button on my camera and the lights on the transceivers will also flash. When I use the test button on the transceivers, both speedlights go off. But when I press the shutter button, my camera will not take a picture. 
Please help!!!!

Comment: Your camera refuses to take an image or your camera takes an image just fine but the flash doesn't fire?

Comment: Is the camera confirming focus?

Comment: Camera focuses just fine but refuses to take a picture.

Comment: What mode is the camera in? Manual, aperture, speed, program?

Answer (score 1):

Are you in live view mode?  Sometimes live view in cameras refuses to fire the shutter or if an external flash or adapter is attached.

Have you tried switching the lens to manual focus?

Have you installed the latest firmware?

Is your self timer on?

Does your hotshoe fire your external flash without issue if it's directly connected?

If all that checks out then it simply may not be possible due to electronic or processor limitations or simply an incompatibilty with your off brand flashes.